# What's the point of having `std::ios_base::width()` and `std::setw()`?

Tags: c++, c++11

Why would I use one over the other?  They both seem to only affect the next field outputted.  What's the point of deliberately having two ways to do the same thing?  Or was one an afterthought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::ios_base::width()` is a member of `ios_base` (ok, that's obvious), which is not typically a class that users mess around with - the intended interface for users is the *stream classes. `std::setw()` works at that level (and eventually calls `std::ios_base::width()` anyway). This enables the coder to write clearer code (my opinion, anyway):

```
cout << setw(10) << someint;
```

instead of:

```
cout.width(10);
cout << someint;
```

Comment: [`ios_base::width` returns a `streamsize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/width) and immediately sets the width of the object (i.e. it's not a stream manipulator).

Comment: @DyP you're right... that makes the second case even uglier; updated with that in mind...

Comment: ... it's NOT a stream manipulator. It isn't inserted in the stream, but called as a regular member function. `cout.width(10);`

Comment: So it's just for convenience.  Syntactic sugar.

Comment: @DyP Doh... corrected again... As you can probably tell, I don't often use the `ios_base::` stuff directly....

Comment: @Adrian More or less, yes. As you can chain several function calls using `operator<<`, you can include the formatting changes in those statements (w/o having to insert a new line). Same for other stream manipulators.

Comment: @Adrian: In as much as _any_ of the stream manipulators are "syntactic sugar", sure. Though it really hasn't got much to do with syntax as these are library, not language grammar, features.